# Suddenly runtime error 13 for no evident reason

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, match, type-mismatch

I'm using a modified match function since years which worked fine. But suddenly I get runtime error 13 for no reason. This function is called two times in the actual process before the error pops up. The first time everything works fine, the second time I get the error. Here's the code:

```
Public Function xMatch(ByRef Direction_Range As Range, ByVal Find_Value_Or_String, Occ_Number As Integer, Row_True_Or_Column_False As Boolean, RelativePosition_True_Or_AbsolutePosition_False As Boolean) As Integer
Dim xMTcell
toolVar1 = 0
xMatch = 0
occurrencesCount = 0
If RelativePosition_True_Or_AbsolutePosition_False = True Then
    If Row_True_Or_Column_False = True Then
        toolVar1 = Range(Split(Direction_Range.Address, ":")(0)).Row - 1
    Else
        toolVar1 = Range(Split(Direction_Range.Address, ":")(0)).Column - 1
    End If
End If
For Each xMTcell In Direction_Range
    If xMTcell.Value = Find_Value_Or_String Then
        occurrencesCount = occurrencesCount + 1
        If occurrencesCount = Occ_Number Then
            If Row_True_Or_Column_False = True Then
                xMatch = xMTcell.Row - toolVar1
            Else
                xMatch = xMTcell.Column - toolVar1
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next xMTcell
End Function
```

toolVar1 and occurrencesCount are declared in the module. The function can search in any ranges (Direction_Range) and find the Value (Find_Value_Or_String). In contrary to a regular match function you can decide (Occ_Number) which find will be the one you need if there are multiple ones in that range. Also, you can decide if you want the row or the column of that find and if you want that row/column absolute (position compared to worksheet) or relative (position compared to Direction_Range).

The error occurs in this line:

`If xMTcell.Value = Find_Value_Or_String Then`

Since xMTcell is part of Direction_Range I checked the Range and it is clearly the right one plus it IS a range and nothing else. I also checked the Value and it is a String he is looking for which can be found manually in that range. I can't understand why it works fine in other stages of the process with the exact same type of Direction_Range and Find_Value_Or_String and suddenly it doesn't. I already tried declaring xMTcell as Range but it made no difference.

Anyone an idea?

Regards
Carl

---

According to the comments i did following checks:

```
Debug.Print VarType(Direction_Range)
Debug.Print Direction_Range.Address
Debug.Print VarType(xMTcell.Value)
Debug.Print VarType(Find_Value_Or_String)
Debug.Print xMTcell.Address
```

and for the non-bugging process i get

```
8204
$A$4:$N$4
8
8
$B$4
```

and for the bugging process

```
8204
$A$5:$A$16
8204
8
$A$5:$A$16
```

so its a problem with the range, why does it behave differently?

Comment: What are the values of `xMTcell` and `Find_Value_Or_String` when the error occurs?

Comment: Look for `#N/A` or `#VALUE!` or `#REF!` errors on your worksheet. These values have a `Variant/Error` data type that is going to throw a *type mismatch* every single time you try to compare them to anything other than a `Variant/Error`. Use the `IsError` function to test a variant for its subtype and return `True` when that subtype is `Error`.

Comment: @BigBen `xMTcell` shows no Value on Mouseover (as ranges do), `Find_Value_Or_String` shows a String

Comment: You can use `Debug.Print`. Check the output in the Immediate Window (use Ctrl+G to bring it up). Also useful: `Debug.Print VarType(xMTcell.Value)`, `Debug.Print VarType(Find_Value_Or_String)`.

Comment: `xMTcell` shows nothing on mouseover because you haven't declared a data type for it, so any member calls against it are late bound. Looks like it's a `Range` object, it should be declared as such.

Comment: @Mathieu The Worksheet has no such errors, within the `Direction_Range` there are only entries like `"ORDER-21-04-3"`. The `Find_Value_Or_String` has the value `"ORDER-21-01-1` when the error occurs. This entry is within the search-range.

Comment: @BigBen VarType shows `8204` for `xMTcell` and `8` for `Find_Value_or_String`. I also tested this in the process when the function doesn't get the error and then both variables have VarType `8`. But what is causing this difference?

Comment: @Mathieu doesn't make a difference if I declare it as Range or not, same difference in VarType as described before according to BigBens advice

Comment: I know it won't. But at least you get *some kind* of type safety. I get 8204 for `VarType(Range("A1:A2").Value)`, so you are looking at a 2D variant array and comparing it to a `Variant/String`, and that will be a type mismatch every single time. Get rid of merged cells and/or make your code work off single cells.

Comment: `8204` would mean that `xMTcell` is a multi-cell range, not a single cell. Can also be verified by using `Debug.Print xMTcell.Address`. Most likely you're passing a `Row` or `Column` for `Direction_Range`. Probably solved by using `For Each xMTcell In Direction_Range.Cells`.

Comment: @BigBen at that point this is shaping up like an answer, you know ;-)

Comment: Edited my Post so the Debug.Print results can be seen properly, still no idea why there is a difference

Comment: What is the `Direction_Range` parameter you're using when the code fails? Most likely using `Rows` or `Columns`.

Comment: You can simplify `Range(Split(Direction_Range.Address, ":")(0)).Row` to `Direction_Range(1,1).Row` and similarly for `.Column`,  potentially avoiding issues for whole-row/whole-column versions of `Direction_Range`

Comment: @Joffan Doing this causes runtime error 1004 in that line. The original code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

Change `For Each xMTcell In Direction_Range` to `For Each xMTcell In Direction_Range.Cells`.

---

Some debugging and general tips (summarizing the comments and your feedback in them):

- `Dim xMTcell` - make that a `Range`.
- Use `Debug.Print` (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the Immediate Window and inspect the output).
- `Debug.Print VarType(xMTcell.Value)` returns `8204`: Per the [`VarType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) docs, that means that `xMTcell.Value` is a `vbArray` of `vbVariant`s (8192 + 12 = 8204).
- `Debug.Print VarType(Find_Value_or_String)` returns `8`: Again per the `VarType` docs, this means `Find_Value_or_String` is a `String`.
- The type mismatch is because you can't compare a `String` to an array.
- The fact that `xMTCell.Value` is an array points to `xMTCell` being a *multi-cell* range, not a single cell.
- ... which is verified by the output of `Debug.Print xMTcell.Address` being a multi-cell range.
- Most likely the issue is that you passed a `Row` or `Column` as your `Direction_Range`, i.e. you used `Rows` or `Columns` to return a range. When looping over a `Row` or `Column`, you need to specify that you're looping over the individual cells.

Comment: That is in fact the difference. In the working process I give `Direction_Range` an `Range(cells...,cells...)` in the non-working process it gets `someRange.Columns(1)`. Unless i want to change it everwhere, how can I tell the `For Each` function it shall take cell by cell regardless of passing `Range(cells...,cells...)` or `Range.Columns(x)` to `Direction_Range` ?

Comment: Does `For Each xMTcell In Direction_Range.Cells` not work? (perhaps you skipped over the TLDR).